# Arduino RC 522 write and read data

Tags: arduino, rfid, mfrc522

I'm working on Arduino RC 522 RFID module. I'm want to write some data in the RFID card and read that data to operate a relay. So is that possible? I want to store integer data in the RFID CARD(13.5Mhz).

Answer (score 1):

for writing the card you can try with this code, change the variable "blockData" with the integer, the lenght should be 16 bytes or you have to change the dimensions of the arrays and for cycles.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

/*Using Hardware SPI of Arduino */
/*MOSI (11), MISO (12) and SCK (13) are fixed */
/*You can configure SS and RST Pins*/
#define SS_PIN 10  /* Slave Select Pin */
#define RST_PIN 7  /* Reset Pin */

/* Create an instance of MFRC522 */
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
/* Create an instance of MIFARE_Key */
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;          

/* Set the block to which we want to write data */
/* Be aware of Sector Trailer Blocks */
int blockNum = 2;  
/* Create an array of 16 Bytes and fill it with data */
/* This is the actual data which is going to be written into the card */
byte blockData [16] = {"Electronics-Hub-"};

/* Create another array to read data from Block */
/* Legthn of buffer should be 2 Bytes more than the size of Block (16 Bytes) */
byte bufferLen = 18;
byte readBlockData[18];

MFRC522::StatusCode status;

void setup() 
{
  /* Initialize serial communications with the PC */
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /* Initialize SPI bus */
  SPI.begin();
  /* Initialize MFRC522 Module */
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  Serial.println("Scan a MIFARE 1K Tag to write data...");
}

void loop()
{
  /* Prepare the ksy for authentication */
  /* All keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory */
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
  /* Look for new cards */
  /* Reset the loop if no new card is present on RC522 Reader */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  
  /* Select one of the cards */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println("**Card Detected**");
  /* Print UID of the Card */
  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.print("\n");
  /* Print type of card (for example, MIFARE 1K) */
  Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
  MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
  Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
         
   /* Call 'WriteDataToBlock' function, which will write data to the block */
   Serial.print("\n");
   Serial.println("Writing to Data Block...");
   WriteDataToBlock(blockNum, blockData);
   
   /* Read data from the same block */
   Serial.print("\n");
   Serial.println("Reading from Data Block...");
   ReadDataFromBlock(blockNum, readBlockData);
   /* If you want to print the full memory dump, uncomment the next line */
   //mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
   
   /* Print the data read from block */
   Serial.print("\n");
   Serial.print("Data in Block:");
   Serial.print(blockNum);
   Serial.print(" --> ");
   for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)
   {
     Serial.write(readBlockData[j]);
   }
   Serial.print("\n");
}



void WriteDataToBlock(int blockNum, byte blockData[]) 
{
  /* Authenticating the desired data block for write access using Key A */
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, blockNum, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK)
  {
    Serial.print("Authentication failed for Write: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Authentication success");
  }

  
  /* Write data to the block */
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(blockNum, blockData, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK)
  {
    Serial.print("Writing to Block failed: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Data was written into Block successfully");
  }
  
}

void ReadDataFromBlock(int blockNum, byte readBlockData[]) 
{
  /* Authenticating the desired data block for Read access using Key A */
  byte status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, blockNum, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));

  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK)
  {
     Serial.print("Authentication failed for Read: ");
     Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
     return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Authentication success");
  }

  /* Reading data from the Block */
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(blockNum, readBlockData, &bufferLen);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK)
  {
    Serial.print("Reading failed: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Block was read successfully");  
  }
  
}
```

For reading data use this code, change "mioCod" with the UID of the card

```
void ceckRFID(){
  //check new cards
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  //If read UID
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    return;
  }
  
  String codLetto = ""; //clean the reading string
  
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) { //save the code into the string
    codLetto += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  
  codLetto.toUpperCase(); //uppercase the string
  Serial.println(codLetto); //print the code

  if(codLetto == mioCod){ //if the code match with mioCod 
      Serial.println("Code recognized");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Wrong code");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi bro.  I've tested write and read data code. It's working fine. But the problem that I faced is, by using write data and read data code I can check my stored data in the card, which is an array, and this data was print by using "Serial. write()". So is that any possibility to convert or store this Serial. write data into a variable. so I can able to operate a relay. I'm not want to use the RFID Card UID in the code.